# Hottest questions this year ? this Century?

Tags: support, search, hot-questions

Is it possible to check the hottest questions of this year ? This century ?

I tried to input : https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=year

but that didn't work.

Comment: You probably won't be browsing Stack Overflow for 100 years (especially considering it's not even 10 years old)... so why not just "all time" (which we have)?

Comment: All time is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes For of the year, try the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

Comment: @DavidRobinson question hotness != question score.

Comment: @Stijn: network hotness isn't even recorded, let alone rankable.

Comment: Not _exactly_ the hottest questions of all time, but close enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits

Comment: @Yannis, cool, didn't know about that. The [first item in the list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477906/password-must-be-8-characters-including-1-uppercase-letter-1-special-character) looks like a false positive though (if that's a greatest hit, then I'm Michael Jackson).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That one has a large anonymous and low rep unique positive feedback count. 3575 with only 500K views, when the second one has 2669 with 2.2M views. That said, the algorithm certainly isn't perfect.

Comment: @Yannis, oh, [that anonymous feedback thingie](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)? I completely forgot about it. That explains much.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ["It would amount to little more than a tool to feed speculation and paranoia..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250550/165773) :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250708/what-does-qanswers-mean-in-the-formula-for-selecting-hot-questions/250726#250726) on MSE I assume I can simply add an extra where clause to take a [certain period into account](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/334508/hotness-for-a-period?startdate=2015-01-01):

```sql
/*
(log(Qviews)*4) + ((Qanswers * Qscore)/5) + sum(Ascores)
--------------------------------------------------------
((QageInHours+1) - ((QageInHours - Qupdated)/2)) ^ 1.5
*/

select top 1000 
(
(log(qviews)*4) + ((qanswers * qscore)/5) + sumascores
)/( 
power( (qageinhours+1) - ((qageinhours - qupdated)/2), 1.5) 
) as hotness
, id as [Post Link]
from (
select viewcount as qviews
    , answercount as qanswers
    , score as qscore
    , ISNULL((select sum(score) 
       from posts 
       where parentid = q.id
       and creationdate > ##startdate:string## ),0) as sumascores
   , datediff(hh, creationdate, getdate()) as qageinhours
   , datediff(hh, lastactivitydate, getdate()) as qupdated
   , id
from posts q
where q.posttypeid = 1 -- Q
and creationdate > ##startdate:string## 
)  rawdata
where qviews>0
order by 1 desc -- yeah I know order by ordinal is bad
```